# Installing Git and Mercurial on the same machine

Tags: git, mercurial

I have Mercurial installed on my machine, which I used to work on for one collaboration project.

Now I am starting another project and want to try out Git.

Should I keep anything in mind when I install both Mercurial and Git on the same client.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 12):

No, nothing. Just install **GIT**. Both client (and eventually servers) can live happy in the same machine.